# POST, move_uploaded_file, sql query error in php form

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, move-uploaded-file

So I'm working on a project for a relatively simple e-commerce website. I've been trying to implement a form that allows users to post products on the said site and attach images. I set a condition to check if it's empty and it works quite alright, but the moment that condition isn't met, the else clause just doesn't seem to execute

Here's the part code;

```php
<?php
include('../Includes/connect.php');

    if(isset($_POST['insert_product'])){
    $prod_title=$_POST['product_title'];
    $desc=$_POST['description'];
    $kw=$_POST['product_keywords'];
    $prod_cat=$_POST['product_category'];
    $price=$_POST['product_price'];
    $prod_status='true';

    //images
    $p_img1=$_FILES['product_image1'] ['name'];
    $p_img2=$_FILES['product_image2'] ['name'];
    $p_img3=$_FILES['product_image3'] ['name'];
    
    //image temp name
    $tmp_img1=$_FILES['product_image1'] ['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_img2=$_FILES['product_image2'] ['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_img3=$_FILES['product_image3'] ['tmp_name'];

    //checking empty conditions
    if($prod_title=='' or $desc=='' or $kw=='' or $prod_cat=='' or $price=='' or $p_img1=='' or   $p_img2=='' ){
        echo "<script>('Please fill all the available fields')</script>";
        exit();   
    }else{
        
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_img1,"../Images/prod_imgs/$p_img1");
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_img2,"../Images/prod_imgs/$p_img2");
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_img3,"../Images/prod_imgs/$p_img3");

        //insert query
        $insert_product = "insert into products (prod_title,prod_desc,prod_keyword,cat_id,prod_img1,prod_img2,prod_img3,date,status,price) 
        values('$prod_title','$desc','$kw','$prod_cat','$p_img1','$p_img2','$p_img3',NOW(),'$prod_status','$price')";

        $result_query=mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);
        if($result_query){
            echo "<script>alert('Successfully inserted product')</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And my database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFRqy.png)

I tried placing an echo before the else clause and it works, it's only on the else where it won't execute. All it does is redirect the current window to a blank page without the pop up or an error

Comment: "doesn't seem to execute" really reduces your chances of getting an answer. Maybe elaborate on that part? Is there an error? If so - please share the stacktrace. If not - what you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Please change your insert query to parameterized prepared statement which is resilient against SQL injection

Comment: Not sure if this is intended but you don't check if `$p_img3` is empty in your `if` clause.

Comment: "_And my database_" That doesn't look like your database

Comment: you missed `alert` inside script tag of `if` part.

Comment: The `rating` column isn't in your query, and yet it cannot be NULL in your table definition, so I would expect that would cause a problem. But that would suggest that the images are being moved correctly, which is not how I read your description of the problem.

Comment: @Greg I will make sure I change them! Whenever I hit my submit button and the php code get's executed, it opens a blank page and nothing happens. However, the condition statement that checks whether it is empty or not works fine

Comment: @droopsnoot Ooooooohhhhh I should try to do that in my DB, thank you!

Comment: @Avnee.Angel I have uploaded the pic of the proper database, can you see it?

Comment: @droopsnoot I made it possible for rating to be null, however it's the same result. As for the files being moved correctly, I made sure the folder is there and working. I'll see if putting an absolute path would fix anything

Comment: @Avnee.Angel I put the proper alert, it seems that the first condition is continuously being met and won't run the else statement, even if all fields are filled. I'm thinking it might be my names in my html code

Comment: You can easily check if it's the names in your HTML table fields with `var_dump($_POST); exit;` at the start of your code, which in fairness is pretty much the very first step when debugging a form submission problem.

Comment: On moving the files, I was asking you whether the files were moved but the query was not executed, or whether the files were also not moved. The former would indicate that it's getting into the `else` clause, whereas the latter would indicate that it is not.

Comment: Don't mark your post as "solved" in the title please (I've rolled that back for you). This site isn't like a traditional forum. If there's an answer which works for you, then mark it as accepted - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). However the answer you've posted currently appears to contain syntax errors, so it's unclear how that could be the solution. Double-check you've provided us your real code. And take the [tour] to ensure you fully understand how Stackoverflow's question and answer system works.

Comment: @stevenndengi "Whenever I hit my submit button and the php code get'..." edit your question and put this detail there, don't expect people to dig for details in comments. In any case - check the server logs. Blank page might be cause of an exception - you might find the details there.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, the syntax needed to be different in the If statement;

```
if($prod_title==" or $desc==" or $kw==" or $prod_cat==" or $price=="" or $p_img1==" or $p_img2=="){
  echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the available fields')</script>";
  exit();
```

Comment: That's invalid code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).